# Getting 0.0 on NumberAnalyzer.java. Need helps

Tags: java, arrays

Write a class with a constructor that accepts a file name as its argument. Assume the file contains a series of numbers, each written on a separate line. The class should read the contents of the file into an array, and then displays the following data.

- The lowest number in the array
- The highest number in the array
- The total of the numbers in the array
- The average of the numbers in the array.

The file, Numbers.txt used for the above program contains these twelve numbers:

```
8.71
7.94
3.01
29.27
9.23
82.76
12.6
47.99
63.89
1.09
22.23
79.17
```

This is the main program: NumberAnalyzerDemo.java

```
import java.io.*;    // Needed for IOException

/**
   This program demonstrates a solution to the
   Number Analysis Class programming challenge.
*/

public class NumberAnalyzerDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // Create a NumberAnalyzer object.
      NumberAnalyzer na = new NumberAnalyzer("Numbers.txt");

      // Display data about the numbers in the file.
      System.out.println("The lowest number in the file is " +
                         na.getLowest());
      System.out.println("The highest number in the file is " +
                         na.getHighest());
      System.out.println("The total of the numbers in the file is " +
                         na.getTotal());
      System.out.println("The average of the numbers in the file is " +
                         na.getAverage());
   }
}
```

This is the class: NumberAnalyzer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

/**
The NumberAnalyzer class is to searching the numbers in a file.
*/
public class NumberAnalyzer
{
    private double[] numbers;
    private int count;
    File file;
    Scanner scan;

    /**
    Constructer that accepts the file name as its argument.
    */
    public NumberAnalyzer(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        count = 0;
        file = new File("Numbers.txt");
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        numbers = new double[11];
    }

    /**
    The getLowest() method to search the file and pull out the lowest
    number in the file.
    @return Return the lowest number.
    */
    public double getLowest()
    {
        double low = numbers[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if (low > numbers[i])
            {
                low = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return low;
    }

    /**
    The getHighest() method to search the file and pull out the highest
    number in the file.
    @return Return the highest number.
    */
    public double getHighest()
    {
        double high = numbers[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if (high < numbers[i])
            {
                high = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return high;
    }

    /**
    This method calculate the total of all the number in the file.
    @return Adding all number in the file.
    */
    public double getTotal()
    {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            total += numbers[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    /**
    This method used to calculate the average of the numbers in the file.
    @return Using the getTotal() divided to the length of the numbers.
    */
    public double getAverage()
    {
        return getTotal() / numbers.length;
    }

    /**
    This method to read all the file txt and get the right number.
    */
    private void getNumbers(String filename)
    {
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            numbers[count] = scan.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    /**
    This method
    */
    private int getNumberOfValues(String filename)
    {
        return count ;
    }
}
```

I'm getting 0.0 for all the output. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to test this on your own? Add some print statements to the code. Does it read in the number successfully? Add them up? Try to find out which step is failing before expecting us to do your work for you.

Comment: Yep, which step is failing?

Comment: Where is getNumbers() method being called? That is the step that reads in the numbers.

Comment: Do you ever make the call to _getNumbers()_? (Or am I just missing it?)

Comment: I think of the getNumberOfValues() method need some changes.

Comment: Should I call the getNumbers() in the main method?

Comment: @NhokV It's up to you. I'd probably call it in your constructor, as per my answer, but your main method would work as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

change you method

```
private void getNumbers(String filename)
```

to

```
public void getNumbers()
```

and then do

```
NumberAnalyzer na = new NumberAnalyzer("Numbers.txt");
na.getNumbers();
```

Comment: It is an error sir!

NumberAnalyzerDemo.java:14: error: method getNumbers in class NumberAnalyzer cannot be applied to given types;
      na.getNumbers();
        ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: fixed that for you

Comment: Still error. Error says it private for the getNumbers(), but when I change to public It still shows error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
 at NumberAnalyzer.getNumbers(NumberAnalyzer.java:99)
 at NumberAnalyzerDemo.main(NumberAnalyzerDemo.java:14)

Comment: you're reading 12 numbers but only allocating 11 in the array. Need to allocate 12 or use an ArrayList() and add or better yet to calculate stats while reading in each number.

Comment: I got it sir. Thanks for helping. Changed from [11] to [12] and it work.

Comment: I would call the getNumbers(); at the constructor to clean my main program. Thank you!

Comment: I guess there are differing opinions, but I personally would not.  If the is a chance of an Exception being thrown, then I would call this code from outside of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your `getNumbers()` method, and so haven't populated your `numbers[]` array.

Just make the call in your constructor, like this:

```
public NumberAnalyzer(String filename) throws IOException
        {
            count = 0;
            file = new File("Numbers.txt");
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            numbers = new double[11];
            getNumbers();
        }
```

It looks like it doesn't need to have the String argument, so you could remove that, unless you're still planing to implement something with it.

Comment: @NhokV Have a look at the comment by JasonM1 above.